# Collectors.toList() showing error "Expected 3 argument but found 1"

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Why is my collect `Collectors.toList()` showing this error:

> Expected 3 argument but found 1

```
package com.knoldus;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


interface Cityeration<T> {
    public abstract List<T> Cityeration(List<T> first, List<T> Second);
}

public class ListMultiplication {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        List firstList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List secondList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        Cityeration c = (first, second) -> IntStream.range(0, first.size())
                        .map(i -> first.get(i) * second.get(i))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using an `IntStream`. It doesn't have a `.collect(Collector<...>)` method, does it? Seems you're expecting to use the collectors available for `Stream<T>`

Comment: Put `.boxed()` before the collect.

Comment: (Or use `mapToObj` instead of `map`)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

interface Cityeration<T> {
    public abstract List<T> cityeration(List<T> first, List<T> Second);
}

public class ListMultiplication {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        List<Integer> firstList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        List<Integer> secondList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        Cityeration<Integer> c = (first, second) -> IntStream
                .range(0, first.size() <= second.size() ? first.size() : second.size())
                .map(i -> first.get(i) * second.get(i)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(c.cityeration(firstList, secondList));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

**Note:** Make sure to

1. use generic types instead of raw types.
2. compare the sizes of the lists to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I appreciate that you added generic types to firstList and secondList.  Similarly, I believe `Cityeration c` should be `Cityeration<Integer> c`.

Comment: @VGR - Thanks for catching it. I've updated the answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger for pointing it out. I've updated my answer to incorporate your comment.

Comment: You also have to remove point 3 from your list (or make it 1 *or* 3). Note further that instead of `.map(...).boxed()`, you can also use `.mapToObj(...)`

Comment: Thanks again, @Holger for it. I've made the change now.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be using collect method of Intstream. This has 3 parameters.
Had it been "Stream", it had single parameter as u expected.